# Notification ignore Alarm setup and starts immediately

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to pop up notification at a specific time but since I set the alarm it begins immediately ignoring the given time

```
public class ShowTaskNotificationService extends IntentService {
private Long date_days;
private Long date_time;

public ShowTaskNotificationService() {
    super("ShowTaskNotificationService");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
     date_days = intent.getLongExtra("Date_days",-1);
     date_time = intent.getLongExtra("Date_time",-1);
     return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    startAlarm();
}
private void startAlarm()
{
    int year,month,day,hour,minute;
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar_days = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_days.setTimeInMillis(date_days);

    Calendar calendar_time = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar_time.setTimeInMillis(date_time);



    year   = calendar_days.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month  = calendar_days.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day    = calendar_days.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    hour   = calendar_time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute = calendar_time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    //Date date = new Date();
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    //cal_alarm.clear();
    //cal_alarm.setTime(date);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("cal_alarm",cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);


}
```

}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        private static String CHANNEL_ID = "taskNoti";

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "channel name";
                String description = "channel description";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Task time")
                    .setContentText("aaa")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            notificationManager.notify(12344, mBuilder.build());
            mBuilder.build();

        }
```

}

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static String CHANNEL_ID = "taskNoti";

@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                CharSequence name = "channel name";
                String description = "channel description";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
                channel.setDescription(description);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Task time")
                    .setContentText("aaa")
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            notificationManager.notify(12344, mBuilder.build());
            mBuilder.build();

        }
```

}

I get the time from another fragment and I pass it to ShowTaskNotificationService class and then get it as Long variables (date_days,date_time)

Answer (score 0):

What is the time are you trying to set?
As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) if the trigger time you specify is in the past, the alarm triggers immediately. That is what's happening in your case. As you are specifying the same time as current time in cal_alarm.
Choose a time at which you want alarm to go off. Something like this:

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.  
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);    
// Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.m.  
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());  
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
```

Comment: I have done that but instead of passing the value directly I pass the variable int year;

Comment: What is the time are you trying to set?  
This code seems to be setting the exact same time as the current time   
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);    
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);    
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day;    
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);    
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);